# Change text when slideTogge

Tags: jquery

I have a menu that is hidden by default. To show the menu with slideToggle I have a simple text button with the text "Show map menu". When I click on the text button to open the menu, I want the text to change to "Hide map menu".

The code below works just once. When I slideToggle back, the text is still "Hide map menu". I have tested other combinations to move the if-statement after the click event, but still not perfect.Is there a way to improve the code?

```
    //Map menu
$("#map-menu-container-btn").click(function(){
$("#map-menu-container").slideToggle("fast");

    if ($("#map-menu-container").is(':visible')) {
         $("p#text-map-menu").text("Hide map menu");               
    } else {
         $("p#text-map-menu").text("Show map menu");              
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
$("#map-menu-container").slideToggle("fast", function() {
    if ($(this).is(':visible')) {
        $("p#text-map-menu").text("Hide map menu");               
    } else {
        $("p#text-map-menu").text("Show map menu");              
    }
});
```

the callback function will be fired **after** your slide animation has finished.

[More info](http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/#callback-function)